# Why does type inference for lambda differ from standard declaration?

Tags: haskell

In GHCI, if I use `:t` on each of the below functions, they differ.

`:t test` gives `(Ord p, Num p) => p -> p -> p`

`:t testAsLambda` gives `Integer -> Integer -> Integer`

Why does using a lambda to define the exact same function cause more restrictive type inference?

I understand that it might be silly to declare a named function as a lambda like this; I'm just trying to reason about Haskell's type inference here.

```
test x y =
  let d = y - x in
   if d > 0 then d
   else 0

testAsLambda = 
  (\x y -> 
   let d = y - x in
    if d > 0 then d
    else 0)
```

Comment: Not reproducible here. Which version of GHC are you using?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. This happens only when the definitions given are placed in an `.hs` file and then either compiled by GHC or `:load`ed *from the file* by GHCi. GHCi's prompt itself is subject to `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction` by default so you will not see this if you just paste the code into GHCi.

Comment: @HTNW Yes! I guess I didn't know the right terms to search for. I used the flag mentioned in that post to turn off monomorphism restriction in GHCI, and now the lambda version's type signature matches the other. Thanks!